# How to get authenticated user in PHP variable "REMOTE_USER" without enabling IIS windows authentication on the whole Joomla site?

Tags: iis, joomla, active-directory

I have a joomla site that is running on IIS server. I enabled windows authentication on the site so that the single sign-on (SSO) plugin can get the authenticated user inside the PHP variable "REMOTE_USER". When the user of the active directory opens the website, it will automatically sign in that user without entering the credentials.

[image]

I intend my site to be public as well. If a user is not part of the active directory he/she can still use the website. However, with windows authentication set on the site, it will prompt the user to enter username and password or deny access to the site if the user is not part of active directory. I want the prompt not to show up and let public user browse the site.

[image]

The following is the code that retrieves the authenticated user and returns it for the other part of the plugin can process it for SSO. This username that is found in the PHP variable "REMOTE_USER" is very important.

*C:\IIS_Sites\joomla2\plugins\sso\http\http.php*

```
        /*
         * When legacy flag is true, it ensures compatibility with JSSOMySite 1.x by
         * only returning a string username or false can be returned. This also means
         * keeping compatibility with Joomla 1.6.
         * When it is set to False, it can return an array and compatible with Joomla 2.5.
         */
        $legacy = $this->params->get('use_legacy', false);

        // Get the array key of $_SERVER where the user can be located
        $serverKey = strtoupper($this->params->get('userkey', 'REMOTE_USER'));

        // Get the $_SERVER key and ensure its lowercase and doesn't filter
        if ($legacy)
        {
            // Get the $_SERVER value which should contain the SSO username
            $remoteUser = JRequest::getVar($serverKey, null, 'server', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the $_SERVER value which should contain the SSO username
            $input = new JInput($_SERVER);
            $remoteUser = $input->get($serverKey, null, 'USERNAME');
            unset($input);
        }

        // Ensures the returned user is lowercased
        $remoteUser = strtolower($remoteUser);

        // Get a username replacement parameter in lowercase and split by semi-colons
        $replace_set = explode(';', strtolower($this->params->get('username_replacement', '')));

        foreach ($replace_set as $replacement)
        {
            $remoteUser = str_replace(trim($replacement), '', $remoteUser);
        }

        // Returns the username
        return $remoteUser;
```

**Is there a way for IIS not to show the username and password prompt/dialog incase of other users (not AD users)?**

Comment: If you read more about IIS, you will see it is an "all or nothing" case. Common practice is to set up two sites, one with Windows authentication on and for internal users, and the other with Windows authentication off and for external users (and there you must use another authentication method and `REMOTE_USER` won't work).

Comment: @LexLi Yes, I believe so because i tried different ways to get it to work both ways but it couldn't. I will implement your solution which is to set up two sites. Thanks for your answer, it truly helped clarify my issue.